# How to get rid of "SMS is no longer supported" notification

Tags: sms, notifications, google-hangouts

My 5.1.1 tablet has an icon in the notification area. It looks like a Google Hangouts icon.  But the drop-down reads "SMS is no longer supported. To read and send SMS messages, please download Android Messenger".

Well, this tablet is wifi only, so I could never send SMS messages anyway (except faking it with Google Voice).  The annoying thing is, there is apparently no way to get rid of this notification icon.  I even tried installing Android Messages to see if that helped, but it didn't.

How can I get rid of this annoying and useless (to me) notification icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried turning off SMS option inside of Hangouts?

Comment: Thanks, while not strictly correct, your answer at least got me to open Hangouts.  There was a notification in the app to choose a different SMS app, and when I did, the problem notification disappeared. So thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: unintall / disbale hangout and instead install "Hangouts chats" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.dynamite

Comment: I don't see any SMS option inside Hangouts.

Comment: @suraj Google chat (or as you say "Hangouts chats") is only for G suite accounts.

Comment: This answer should not be accepted - there is no SMS option in hangouts. I also don't see any way of selecting a different SMS app (perhaps because I don't have one installed? But I have no need for one,  as my tablet doesn't have a mobile connection so can't send or receive SMS anyway, so I don't really want to install one).