# Hangouts Notification - SMS no longer supported

Tags: google-hangouts

I just got an Android tablet (Lenovo 4 8") after using an iPad for a couple of years or so.

I'm getting the "SMS is no longer supported" notification from Hangouts repeatedly and I can't seem to get rid of it.

I've tried opening Hangouts and trying to find a setting to let me get rid of this message, or to declare an alternate SMS app (I have one).  But the instructions I've been able to find must be for an older version of the interface, because there's no Options menu item and I can't find an option in Settings to help.

[How to get rid of "SMS is no longer supported" notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177675/how-to-get-rid-of-sms-is-no-longer-supported-notification)

I use Hangouts all the time and I'd like to continue using it.  But the SMS message is really annoying.

Comment: unintall / disbale hangout and instead install "Hangouts chats" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.dynamite

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are getting this message again and again because Hangout is still registered as the default app to handle SMS messages (which it doesn't support anymore).

Therefore have to make a different app the default SMS app. To do so open the Android **Settings** app (the gear icon) and select the **Apps and Notifications** section (might be named a little different on your device depending on the Android version and manufacturer).

There you will find an entry that allows you to select the **Default SMS** app. If you can't choose the app your device may be missing an app that can handle SMS. In such a case search the Google PlayStore for an new [SMS app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=SMS&c=apps).

Comment: That didn't work. I don't have Hangouts as default sms app and still get the notification

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same notification. I did what was suggested in the comment above...went to SETTINGS, then APPS AND NOTIFICATIONS, then DEFAULT APP.  I selected the "messages" app that came with the phone because that's what i was already using. This did not clear the notification so...I opened the list of all apps and UNINSTALLED the Hangouts app.  That worked! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Apps -> Gear icon top right -> SMS settings
You have to download an alternate SMS app for it to work. I suggest GoSMS.
Restart tablet.